# How can I get the last element of an array? SQL Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm working on building a follow-network form  Github's available data on Google BigQuery, e.g.: https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/githubarchive:day.20210606

The key data is contained in the "payload" field, STRING type. I managed to unnest the data contained in that field and convert it to an array, but how can I get the last element?

Here is what I have so far...

```
select type, 
  array(select trim(val) from unnest(split(trim(payload, '[]'))) val) payload
from `githubarchive.day.20210606` 
where type = 'MemberEvent'
```

Which outputs:

[image]

How can I get only the last element, "Action":"added"} ?
I know that

`select array_reverse(your_array)[offset(0)]`

should do the trick, however I'm unsure how to combine that in my code. I've been trying different options without success, for example:

```
with  payload as ( select  array(select trim(val) from unnest(split(trim(payload, '[]'))) val) payload from `githubarchive.day.20210606`)

select type, ARRAY_REVERSE(payload)[ORDINAL(1)]

from `githubarchive.day.20210606` where type = 'MemberEvent'
```

The desired output should look like:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To get last element in array you can use below approach

```
select array_reverse(your_array)[offset(0)]
```

> I'm unsure how to combine that in my code

```
select  type, array_reverse(array(
    select trim(val) 
      from unnest(split(trim(payload, '[]'))) val
  ))[offset(0)] 
from `githubarchive.day.20210606`
where type = 'MemberEvent'
```

Comment: I've Benn trying that approach without success, I'm new in SQL. How can I plug that along with my code?

Comment: You asked very specific question - "How can I get the last element of an array?" and you got the answer! if you have more/follow-up question(s) - please post it as a new questions with all relevant details including sample of input data as well as expected output  - and we will be happy to help further

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've edited my question to make it clearer

Comment: see update in my answer

Answer (score 3):

There is a solution without reversing the array.

SELECT event[OFFSET(**ARRAY_LENGTH(event)-1**)

Comment: If you're fetching the contents of a nested field, this will be much more efficient than using `ARRAY_REVERSE()`, so should be used instead.